# Trouble getting the content when generating an XML file with Wordpress for Google Maps

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I needed to generate an XML file through Wordpress to be used for generating markers on a Google Map. 
I modified a function I found here: [Write to XML file using fopen in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052516/write-to-xml-file-using-fopen-in-wordpress?s=16ebf83b-664d-45f0-ac2b-e28b42d454b2)

The function runs whenever a post is modified.

The map side of things is working fine. I can generate an XML file which has a title and longitude and latitude for each entry and they are properly plotted on the map.

However I can't seem to get the post content, which I want to use for the address. I can't even get the content just to echo for testing. I've tried encoding the html in case that was conflicting with the XMl, but nothing. Seems to just not be getting any content. Yes I have made sure the posts have content although I am open to the idea I may have missed something simple :-p

My function is below.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'markers_xml' );

function markers_xml(){

if ($_POST['post_type'] == 'places-to-eat') 
{
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
  $markers = get_posts( array( 'post_type'=>'places-to-eat', 'numberposts'=>-1 ) );

  $xml->addChild('markers');

  foreach($markers as $i=>$marker){
    $name = get_the_title($marker->ID);
    $address = get_the_content($marker->ID);
    $address = htmlentities($address);
    $lat = get_post_meta($marker->ID, 'the-lat', true);
    $lng = get_post_meta($marker->ID, 'the-lng', true);  


 $xml->markers->addChild('marker');
 $xml->markers->marker[$i]->addChild('name', $name);
 $xml->markers->marker[$i]->addChild('address', $address);
 $xml->markers->marker[$i]->addChild('lat', $lat);
 $xml->markers->marker[$i]->addChild('lng', $lng);
}

 $file = '/public_html/wp-content/uploads/test.xml';
 $open = fopen($file, 'w') or die ("File cannot be opened.");
 fwrite($open, $xml->asXML());
 fclose($open); 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The title and content are already available to you through the get_posts().  There is no need to use get_the_title() or get_the_content(). The return values for the get_posts() is stated in the [get_post() documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post#Return).  This shows you the data available.

Try this.

```
foreach($markers as $i=>$marker){
//replace this 
//$name = get_the_title($marker->ID);
//with this
$name = $marker->post_title;
//replace this
//$address = get_the_content($marker->ID);
//with this
$address = $marker->post_content;
```